# What Java CMIS client library should I use?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am starting a new project and must decide which [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) client library we will use.
Our Java project just needs to connect an a CMIS server (actually Alfresco but it should not matter), in order to perform some read/write/search operations.

I am looking for a client library that:

- is already usable
- is not going to be abandoned soon
- has an active community of users
- is open source

Which one would you recommend and why?

Here are a few possibilities:

- [Apache Chemistry's OpenCMIS](https://cwiki.apache.org/CMIS/opencmis.html) (winner by now)
- [xCMIS](https://code.google.com/p/xcmis/)

  chemistry-atompub-client (abandoned)

  chemistry-abdera (not very active)

  Abdera (difficult)

  Use the AtomPub or Web Service directly (difficult)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend OpenCMIS. (Well, I have to since I'm involved in the project.)
It's an active project supported by a broad community. OpenCMIS supports both bindings, AtomPub and Web Services, and has been tested against a number of repositories.

chemistry-atompub-client has been abandoned and chemistry-abdera is not very active. You can, of course, handle the AtomPub binding directly, but that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use an Alfresco-specific OpenCMIS extension for the sake of simplicity.

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/alfresco-opencmis-extension/

Comment: I want to be independent from Alfresco. I actually went with OpenCMIS and I am very happy with it :-)

Comment: It's not needed (anymore) of you intend to use CMIS 1.1: Alfresco-specific extension are only meant to manage aspects while using CMIS 1.0.